# SQL Server consuming all my CPU

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I already have a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23874/geoserver-with-sql-server-consuming-all-my-cpu) on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23874/geoserver-with-sql-server-consuming-all-my-cpu) assuming it may be geoserver the problem but as I go deeper into problem I found that I have a database bottleneck. My SQL server CPU usage is almost 100% when geoserver executes following queries :

```
SELECT "siteId","Vendor",CAST("SP_GEOMETRY".STSrid as VARCHAR) 
  + ':' + "SP_GEOMETRY".STAsText() as "SP_GEOMETRY" FROM "LiveData"."sites"
         WHERE ("SP_GEOMETRY".Filter(
    geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON 
    ((87.16003722182671 27.034666490477207, 
      87.16003722182671 28.328562656235395, 
      88.62121886224784 28.328562656235395, 
      88.62121886224784 27.034666490477207, 
      87.16003722182671 27.034666490477207))', 4326)) = 1 
AND ( UPPER("Vendor") LIKE 'A%'  OR  UPPER("Vendor") LIKE 'B%' ))
```

--

```
SELECT "Site_ID","Vendor",CAST("sp_geometry".STSrid as VARCHAR) 
  + ':' + "sp_geometry".STAsText() as "sp_geometry" 
FROM "LiveData"."sites"
WHERE ("sp_geometry".Filter(geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((
  82.89734190991959 26.99551618775358, 
  82.89734190991959 28.367238076413702,
  84.44641417532948 28.367238076413702, 
  84.44641417532948 26.99551618775358, 
  82.89734190991959 26.99551618775358))', 4326)) = 1 
AND ( UPPER("Vendor") LIKE 'A%'  OR 
 UPPER("Vendor") LIKE 'B%' ))
```

Now the problem is as I open multiple pages **just 4-5 pages** the web pages hangs as it has to retrieve data from database.

I have a view that is made spatial by selecting spatial column **SP_GEOMETRY** from  base table:

```
    CREATE view [LiveData].[sites]
      As
     select
     live.Site_ID as siteId,live.Site_Name,live.Vendor,live.Status,live.MI_SQL_REC_NUM,
     live.MI_STYLE,live.MI_PRINX,live.SP_GEOMETRY
     from baseTble.spatialSites live ,LiveData.liveStatus stat 
where 
live.Site_ID  = stat.siteId and stat.Code in ('x123','y345') and stat.alias = 'Neyman'
```

Comment: What's the structure of the `LiveData` table? Specifically, what indexes are on it?

Comment: Your query is non-SARGable.  You're forcing a scan.  It's optimization practices like eliminating query aspects like that which can lead to better performance.

Comment: While I believe the `geometry` part of the query is your problem, is there an index on `vendor`? The second part of your clause could be simplified to `AND Vendor LIKE '[A-B]%'` (which will work best if there is an index on that column). Also note that using `"double quotes"` for column aliases is deprecated - you should use `'single quotes'` or `[square brackets]`.

Comment: Also, and this is more about best practices than your specific performance issue, but why do you say `VARCHAR` without specifying the length? Please read: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: @SimonRigharts LiveData is schema and sites is view. I have code for view.

Comment: @AaronBertrand as geoserver makes its own query from SLD I can't do much with the query. This is live table so I read that it's better not to index OLTP systems but I don't know if I should index this view and base table?

Comment: Ok, well someone should tell them they're doing it wrong. I don't know who told you you shouldn't index OLTP systems, but unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with spatial to recommend any specific index techniques. I will suggest you use proper INNER JOIN syntax instead of FROM a,b...

Comment: For more info on the FROM a, b bit : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16725/sql-join-syntax-in-ms-sql/

Comment: @AaronBertrand the cost of both query is same :)

Comment: @Kitex: Have you tried using the `STIntersects()` function instead of the `Filter()` ?

Comment: @ypercube these query are executed by geoserver based on sld so I think i need to change sld

Comment: Do you mean that the queries are not explicitely written by you but produced by geoserver and you can't change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try replacing `Filter()` with `STIntersects()`. If the queries are auto-produced by the geoserver, you can test this directly in SQL-Server (so at least you know where the problem is):

```
WHERE
  ( "SP_GEOMETRY".STIntersects( 
      geometry::STGeomFromText(
        'POLYGON ((87.16003722182671 27.034666490477207, 
                   87.16003722182671 28.328562656235395, 
                   88.62121886224784 28.328562656235395, 
                   88.62121886224784 27.034666490477207, 
                   87.16003722182671 27.034666490477207))',
        4326)) = 1 
  AND
     ...
  )
```

---

**(update)**

This page: [Filter: One Odd Duck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/isaac/filter-one-odd-duck) suggests that `Filter()` is just a fast `STIntersects()` with the difference that it may return false positives.

It also suggests that the two functions have the exact same (and slow) performance when there is no usable index. So, the best to do is to create a spatial index (and then replace Filter() with STIntersects(), if you want).

The blog (by @Isaac at MSDN) [SQL Server Spatial Indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/isaac/sql-server-spatial-indexing) has 7 nice articles about spatial indexes.

Comment: the time for query is same

Comment: @Kitex: See my update and the link.

Comment: you were right about index but it already has spatial index. The actual cause was lack of index in base table. IT has made it unbelievably fast. So fast that I forgot the spelling of "unbelievably". Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked much with geospatial types but the fact that it's CPU-intensive isn't all that surprising. If you want to avoid the CPU pegging out at 100% for the server I'd suggest taking a look at your MAXDOP settings at the instance level. The default value is 0 meaning SQL Server will use up all available processors (logical) when processing. If your query is pegging out all your CPUs and causing issue you may want to experiment tweaking your settings. Take a read of @paulrandal's post on MAXDOP: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/MAXDOP-configuration-survey-results.aspx

Word of caution: Don't go changing this willy-nilly in production as it WILL affect performance and the last thing you want is to get yelled at/fired because "some guy on internet said it'd work!". Test your settings in development environment first and see if this works for you.

Comment: Jorge, why at the instance level instead of targeting these specific queries, if they've been identified as the culprit behind the CPU usage?